# unlocking disk sda5_crypt without re-installing

Tags: boot

I have just installed used DBAN to completely clean my old hard drive and then set BIOS to start from the memory stick on which I had burnt ubuntu. After starting and installing ubuntu I tried to start up but get the question
"please unlock disk sda5_crypt" .
I had earlier requested BIOS to set up priorities as "default".
Please help a very doddery computer-ignorant 80 year-old